# How to implement Tab completion in Bash C source code

Tags: c, linux, bash

As a beginner to Linux, I am researching the source of Bash and very interested to Tab completion.

On my opinion, there are two possible implementation of Tab completion.

1. Bash get char '\t' from TTY and call corresponsable completion function to do something based on the chars you have typed.
2. Tab keystroke fire a signal(event?) to bash. Then bash handle this signal and call back to a completion handler.

I made some searching and look up relevant code from Bash source http://sources.debian.net/src/bash/4.3-7 , but I cant find any code related to handle Tab signal or get char '\t' from TTY.

Anyone know the mechanism of Tab completion and can point the location of relevant code? Thanks.

Comment: I believe bash uses the readline library. You should look there instead.

Comment: I searched Bash's source for "completion" and found a few useful results, if it helps: http://codesearch.debian.net/search?q=package%3Abash+completion

Comment: I used termios http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html to hande '\t'. You can use readline too but i have no tired it

Answer (score 3):

Every keystroke you type at a `bash` prompt is bound to a function defined by the `readline` library. (Even the letters--upper and lowercase--are bound to the `self-insert` function, which simply puts the typed character on the command line. A key that is not bound to a function simply has no effect and is ignored.) The <kbd>Tab</kbd> key, by default, is bound to the `complete` function. The effect of the `complete` function is to attempt completion of the text immediately prior to the current cursor position (the *point*, in `readline` parlance). From the `bash` man page.

> complete (TAB)
>                 Attempt to perform completion on the text before point.  Bash attempts completion treating the text as a
>                 variable (if the text begins with $), username (if the text begins with ~), hostname (if the text begins
>                 with @), or command (including aliases and functions) in turn.  If none of these produces a match, file-
>                 name completion is attempted.

(Programmable completion, I believe, is attempted in place of filename completion when applicable.)